# Text is not getting placed as mentioned in  CGRect frame of UILable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

this might look simple but i am  not able to Find the solution for this...when i use this below code the text get placed at right postion as mentioned in the  CGRect frame.

[self.view addSubview:[self createLabel:CGRectMake(50,480,50,20):@"Status:"]];

```
-(UILabel*)createLabel:(CGRect)frame :(NSString*)labelTitle
{
  UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; 
  [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];  
  myLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
}
```

But when i use this below Code the text is getting placed at rightmost corner of the frame...its not getting placed at right position as mentioned in the CGRect frame..can anyone tell whats the problem happening with this..

```
[self.view addSubview:[self createLabel:CGRectMake(50,340,150,20):aRequests.request_details]];
```

NOTE:aRequests.request_details is coming from webservices..

Comment: To me it looks should work. Can you add a background color to the label and check the text alignment against the frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method doesn't return any object. Try to add `return myLabel;` at the end of it.

And you are not setting new title: `myLabel.text = labelTitle;`